# What is the reason for the geometrical magnetoresistance effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What causes the [geometrical magnetoresistance effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance#Geometrical_magnetoresistance)? Sure, it is some kind of geometry but how/why? What is happening on the physical level that the resistance increases (or decreases?) with an applied magnetic field?

Comment: Doesn't the wikipedia page you link to describe it quite well? Due to the geometry/shape of the conductor the velocity of carriers is influenced in a certain way (the shape partially dictates the direction of motion) by the magnetic field.

Comment: From my pov this is not an explanation at all?! This is just a phenomenal observation.

Comment: But why can't it just be a phenomenological effect? There is nothing fundamentally special about it.

Comment: I fear I have to accept it as that. At least I can't find any further explanation behind it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you expect it to be a fundamental effect?

Comment: It's just how I think and try to understand things :)